# Editing .bib files in (n)vim with tailored autocompletion

Tags: filetype, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I use `BibDesk` on a Mac to edit `.bib` files (in biblatex, using `biber` to compile). This generally works, but for various reasons it would be nice to be able to edit them in `nvim` too. My current setup lets me do that reasonably well (I think because of `vimtex` and `vim-snippets`), but I haven't figured out a way to achieve easy "keyword" completion, where here "keyword" means something appearing in any bib-entry's `keywords` field (e.g., `keywords = {keyword1; keyword2}`). `C-N` completes it based on *any* word in the file, not bib-keywords specifically.

Is there any setup or plugin that offers this and other similar completion features comparable to those offered by `BibDesk` (e.g., `author` completion, and in general completion by bib-field, as well as completing by `citekey` when appropriate, for instance in `crossref` fields)?

## Update

As explained by @KarlYngveLervag on [github](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2620), what I should be using is omnicompletion. When I do that in a bib file, it seems to pull up a list of possible *fields* (author, title, year, etc.) that could complete the word I am typing, *even if I am within the braces `{}` of a field itself* (e.g., cursor is `*` in `author = {Ye*}`).

So my question is really about how to make omnicompletion aware of what field the cursor is in.

Comment: Relevant link: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2620

Answer (score 0):

In input (insert or replace) mode, try <kbd>^x</kbd> to enter completion mode selection then <kbd>^n</kbd> to activate buffer based completion.
If you don't have a plugin or a setting in your `~/.vimrc` that's making some interference it would do it  (buffer completion) by default. Otherwise, check `:set complete?` (default value is`complete=.,w,b,u,t`) and `:set omnifunc?` (if not set default, should only be triggered by <kbd>^x</kbd> then <kbd>^o</kbd>) and `:set completefunc?` (usually triggered by <kbd>^x</kbd> then <kbd>^u</kbd>) so we can debug the stuff.

edit: I misread the question and thought you wanted to complete based on other data already inputed, but in fact you are seeking for keywords only right?
Also note that [completion is disabled by vimtex for bib files](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex.vim#L98).

Comment: That didn't work for me. It just pulled up the list of *all words in the file* that could possibly complete what I began to type (rather than only those appearing in the bib field I was in). `:set omnifunc?` returns `omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`, and `:set completefunc?` returns `completefunc=` (with nothing after the `=` sign).

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose: have completion from all words already typed. Sorry, I misunderstood the "that could complete the word I am typing, even if I am within the braces". OK, `completefunc=` (empty) means it's not in use (and <kbd>^x</kbd><kbd>^u</kbd> won't have any effect, but asking myself if it isn't the way to look for.) Omni completion is what you are using, I guess, and we have to dig deeper the function used. First, is it defined in your `~/.vimrc` or sourced from a plugin?

Comment: Edit lat (over five minutes, time to do a local check) Use `:verbose set omnifunc?` to have more information on it's activation...

Comment: Running it verbose tells me that omnifunc is set in my `.vimrc` with the line `set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`.

Comment: OK, check your file that you have it set up [as described in the documentation](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-syntax-omni): it should be on only for file types that can use it. In another hand, VimTeX has no support for that syntax-based completion and [disable it among others](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex.vim#L98) I'll come with another answer a bit later for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Vim can use a keywords file(s) for completion. I setup two with the help of the [biblatex cheatsheet (PDF)](http://tug.ctan.org/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf):

- [`biber_entries.dict`](https://snip.dssr.ch/?a1b590e127987e59#8cSN1tD5TUJ1UvVhGPuctt258cqMgLSEzucuymBXgD2r)
  for the database entries types, and
- [`biber_fields.dict`](https://snip.dssr.ch/?ba8f15e9c76d0b85#7YbcbSHXpEWAyTJ3Z2sg1rhHHrL4So8dWYxq8JtTsGKF)
  for the fields types.

(For the contents of these two files hosted here on this site rather than remotely, see below.)

Now, in my session I have to declare those files for use with the completion

```
:set dictionary=~/.vim/kwd/biber_entries.dict
:set dictionary+=~/.vim/kwd/biber_fields.dict
```

Note that I made my test with the *at* sign in my entries file, but Vim
doesn't consider symbols here, unless it's tell (not tested and usable so)
[to do so](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/option.html#iskeyword)?
There's no way to put comments either, words after `#` or `"` are read too.

```
:set iskeyword+=@
```

Once the [dictionaries
declared](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27dictionary%27),
we're ready to complete based on them, after triggering a [<kbd>^x</kbd>
<kbd>^k</kbd>](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-dictionary).

If happy with the files and that completion, add it permanently in your
`~/.vimrc` but only for Bib files and make the setting local in order to
not disturb the other buffers.

```
au FileType bib execute 'setlocal dict+=~/.vim/kwd/biber_entries.dict,~/.vim/kwd/biber_fields.dict'
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.bib execute 'let &l:dictionary .= "," . tr(expand("~/.vim/kwd/biber_*.dict"), "\n", ",")'
```

There's still one annoyance: continuously switching to dictionary completion
sub mode. By default, <kbd>^n</kbd> and <kbd>^p</kbd>, unless the
appropriate <kbd>^x</kbd> switch, Vim scans: the current buffer (`.`),
buffers from other windows (`w`), other loaded buffers that are in the
buffer list (`b`), the unloaded buffers that are in the buffer list (`u`),
then do tag completion (`t`). Let's change it to always use our words list
first, then the current buffer:

```
:set complete=k,.
```

Now, we have homemade Bib files keywords completion, but also any
[word/name](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-current),
and even [line](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-whole-line)
already there. (full line still require <kbd>^x</kbd><kbd>^l</kbd> and I
cannot found how to add that in the option.) Also, when pleased with that
[option value](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27complete%27),
save it to the `~/.vimrc` and still ensure it's local. Good news, both
actions (defining desired completions and lookup files) can be done in one
step:

```
" also make the following fileType dependent
complete=k~/.vim/kwd/biber_entries.dict,k~/.vim/kwd/biber_fields.dict,.
```

Some people may prefer the use of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/bib.vim` which is
always associated to that file type (hence easier to write: this file is
triggered like an `autocmd fileType`, the cons is that there're more to
backup and restore.) As I don't use `vimtex`, I don't know which method is
more compatible with [its
behaviour](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/c77ec4e15768ffcb97a96d1bf2df1ef58e94acdd/autoload/vimtex.vim).

Last notes.

1. Entries type may not be needed because you use `vim-snippets` which
   let you define nice input templates, just add yours for Bib files. I'm
   also thinking to use such plugin, but for now I'm using abbreviations…
2. There's no need to have two different files and it may be better to
   have one global per file type… I did split because I feel more comfortable
   working in smaller files.
3. For switching between completion methods easily I'm planning to use
   finally [`mucomplete` plugin](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete).
   To be followed.

---

Here are the content of the `.dict` files linked above

First, `biber_entries.dict`:

```
article
periodical
suppperiodical
inbook
suppbook
bookinbook
book
mvbook
incollection
suppcollection
collection
mvcollection
inproceedings
proceedings
mvproceedings
inreference
reference
mvreference
manual
report
patent
thesis
online
booklet
unpublished
misc
set
xdata
```

Second, `biber_fields.dict`:

```
author shortauthor
bookauthor
editor shorteditor
editora editorb editorc
afterword
annotator
commentator
forward
introduction
translator
holder
institution
organization
publisher origpublisher
title titleaddon origtitle shorttitle subtitle
indextitle
booktitle booktitleaddon subbooktitle
maintitle maintitleaddon submaintitle
journaltitle subjournaltitle
issuetitle subissuetitle
eventtitle eventtitleaddon
reprinttitle
series shortseries
volume
number
part
issue
volumes
edition
version
pubstate
pages
pagetotal
pagination bookpagination
date origdate
eventdate
urldate
location origlocation
venue
url
doi
eid
eprint
eprinttype
type
entrysubtype
addendum
note
howpublished
language origlanguage
isan
isbn
ismn
isrn
iswc
abstract
annotation
file
library
related
relatedtype
relatedstring
entryset
crossref
xref
xdata
langid
langidopts
gender
presort
sortkey
sortname
sortshorthand
sorttitle
indexsorttitle
sortyear
execute
keywords
options
ids
```

Comment: I am planning to test this soon, but meanwhile might I ask you to edit your answer to include the contents of `biber_entries.dict` and `biber_fields.dict` rather than linking to a remote site? This would improve the usefulness of this answer in the long run.

Comment: Done. :) Those lists of words are a bit long (when putting one word per line), that's while I avoided those listings here (I was afraid to make the answer uselessly too long.)

Comment: Should the `:set` commands be changed to `:setlocal` so that they apply only to the `.bib` buffer that has been opened?

Comment: I just tested the setup described in this answer but all it seems to do is to allow me to autocomplete *the names of bib entries and bib fields*. But my question was how I can autocomplete based on the *contents of all existing bib entries*. E.g., if there is a `book` entry with the author field `author = {Dylan, Bob}` and then I make a new `article` entry and begin filling the author field by typing `author = {Dy*}` (with my cursor at `*`, I would like to be able to press a key to make `nvim` suggest completing the field as `author = {Dylan, Bob}`.

Comment: Yes `:setlocal` (I made my tests with only one buffer opened.) To fill the author field, that the part: "(full line still require `^x` `^l` and I cannot found how to add that in the option.)" maybe a map? It works with `author = {Dy*` and without any extra setting, but I didn't test with closing brace.

Comment: But then if I understand correctly, this is just full-line completion, with no need for the dictionaries. This is not what I'm looking for because it fails to parse fields containing lists, like `author = {Dylan, Bob and Guthrie, Woody}` or `keywords = {class; America}`. Thus, there is still no way (given the prior existence of these two example fields) to make `keywords = {Am*}` complete to `keywords = {America}`.

Comment: Sorry for being late for clarification. True, line completion needs no dictionary. In fact it's a buffer content based completion but matching a line with the identical starting (that's why you cannot pick up only "America" but "class; America"...) You can switch back to the other buffer content based completion, but it offers all the words of the document without being aware of the line context (there, `^x` `^n` will let you pick "America" but also any word starting with "Am"...) That's why I keep it but put it in second tries after dictionary lookup.

Comment: Nevertheless, this "answer" does not really answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've understood in first place that you wanted to complete _bib-keywords_ and replicate identical lines. :) I played last night around ability to do a context completion of keywords' values, and it seems very difficult (at least for me :D or maybe am i not using the right approach.) If I achieve to got something working I'll publish the plugin (things are wider than a quick answer here) and let you know here.